# Able to connect to MongoDB using mongoose from NodeJS without specifying credentials

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I followed the [link](https://medium.com/@raj_adroit/mongodb-enable-authentication-enable-access-control-e8a75a26d332) to enable authentication to connect to mongodb. It worked only through mongo shell. 
However, I could connect successfully to mongodb from Nodejs application using mongoose library WITHOUT applying authentication mechanism. That is , I used connection string as mongodb://localhost/my_db and it connects successfully without specifying username password. Also when I user mongodb://username:password@localhost/pms_db then too connects. I want Nodejs application to connect to mongodb only and only when username and password is specified. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Achieved success when connecting to mongodb using mongo shell. However, can connect without specifying credentials from NodejS application

Comment: You say you can _connect_ without credentials; but you do know mongodb will let you connect unauthorised? It will only enforce the authentication when you try to do something e.g. read or insert data. If you try to read some data, for example, through your no-credentials connection, does that succeed or fail?

Comment: @Vince. Yes, when I want to use mongodb in terminal I type mongo and the shell starts. But when I type a command such as show dbs it will simple give message not authrized. So before logging onto mongo shell I do have to use the following command.  

mongo --port 27017 -u "username" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"

Comment: @Vince. Thanks, I did not go ahead a step further to check whether my nodejs services are working or not without providing credentials. When I try to hit NodeJS service and the application is connected to MongoDB without credentials then the service does not return anything and simply time out occurs!!